# How can I put this function into a form element button?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a form element in my HTML page that currently retrieves the `toDataURL()` from one canvas(`canvas2`) and draws the image into a second canvas(`outputCanvas`).  What I need is for that onclick event to retrieve the canvas image and use that image in this function.  As of now Im able to manually save the canvas image as a .png and then hard-code the file into this function, but I need this all to happen when the button is clicked.  Im a newb at .js but I can handle pseudo-code if its easier to explain, but please be specific.  The following `draw()` needs to be handled when the click occurs.  I have the listener below that should call the `draw()`.

```
function init () {
         canvas = document.getElementById('anotherCanvas');  
         ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');       
         draw ();
         }

function draw() {   
        img = new Image();  
        img.src = 'recursed1.png';        
        fr1 = makeFrame(ctx,makeVect(400,0), makeVect(400, 0), makeVect(0, 400));
        img.onload = function(){ 
                ctx.save(); 
                newPainter = cornerSplit(imagePainter,5);
                newPainter(fr1);     
                ctx.restore();
                ctx.save();
                newPainter(flipHorizLeft(fr1));
                ctx.restore();
                ctx.save();
                newPainter(flipVertDown(fr1));  
                ctx.restore();
                ctx.save();
                newPainter(flipVertDown(flipHorizLeft(fr1)));   
            }
```

The following is currently independent of the above, I can only get the above function to work if I manually save & hard-code the image created in an independent canvas (canvas2).  I need the two to work together.  The HTML element:

```
<input type="button" id="recImage" value="Recurse Image">


var formElement = document.getElementById("createImageData"); 
formElement.addEventListener('click', createImageDataPressed, false);

function createImageDataPressed(e) { 
  var imageDataDisplay = document.getElementById("imageDataDisplay"); 
  imageDataDisplay.value = canvas2.toDataURL(); 
  var newImagewindow.open(canvas2.toDataURL(),
          "canvasImage","right=300,top=400,width="canvas2.width + ",height=" + 
      canvas2.height + ",toolbar=0,resizable=0");
 }
```

The above is my most recent attempt, it doesn't work... Nothing is set in stone, and If there is a better route than what Im attempting please let me know.  [this work in progress may help you understand what Im trying to do](http://mcgrawtheseeker.com/)

Comment: Im still banging my head, Ive tried your suggestion but my lack of js skills is kinking things up

Comment: See my answer - that what you're looking for? I'm just not too sure what you want.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want `init` and `data` to be called when `formElement` is clicked, right?

Just add a call to `init` and `data` in `createImageDataPressed` or add some more `click` handlers to `formElement`.

Comment: the init() thats associated with the above draw() is only there for me to test the functionality of the draw() method when I hardcode a canvas png into it, My main HTML has an initializer that goes onLoad of window, this, the main initializer starts the drawing functionality for the user. That user defined image is what needs to be retrieved in the onclick and sent to the draw().

Comment: So... what is the logical progression of events that should happen? Be nice and clear

Comment: if you have a chance to check out the above link, it may help, im obviously still working on it but its getting close and my canvas's and temp UI is in place

Comment: I did; can you walk through a logical progression of events please?

Comment: Since right now it appears to work @mcG73 ... since I have no idea what  the final product should look like.

Comment: on original page load, user sees two canvas's. One of which can be drawn upon, when the recurseIt button is clicked, I need that image retrieved by the draw(), and displayed on the second canvas. The draw() function takes there image and creates a fractal-like pattern similar to David Escher's 'Square Limit'.

Comment: the `draw` problem seems to be an issue now, then, since the image copy works in my browser

Comment: If I open the page that handles the actual drawing functionality, not the draw() and create an image, right click on that image, save to HD, and then place that image in the draw() img.src='the newly saved canvas image' it works- Im trying to get this handled with a click of the recurseIt button.

Comment: where do you define `outputCtx` in `recImagePressed`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5433/discussion-between-tekknolagi-and-mcg73)